# Resistors in paralel on pcb schematics?

Tags: resistors, schematics

I know that capacitors in parallel are used for filtering, but what could possibly a resistor in parallel be used for?

Take for example the schematics I pinned to this post https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Ttr.jpg and the resistor I circled in black what could possibly be its use??

[image]

I hope I've been clear enough, Thanks.

Comment: As part of a filter.

Comment: Why are you calling this "in parallel?" What is it in parallel with?

Comment: All right it is kind of in parallel, I guess its in series jut that the output voltage is taken from the resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RC network circled in black is a power on reset circuit.  I have attached a figure from an ST application note [Simple Reset Circuits for the ST6](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fweb%2Fen%2Fresource%2Ftechnical%2Fdocument%2Fapplication_note%2FCD00003839.pdf&ei=X3fOVKB71bHIBI6pgZAE&usg=AFQjCNEiVa1RsXQjdFN7Kxlr-LAuQUMW9A&sig2=mXynzswjVoROlSfeQzyoQw)

[image: por circuit]

It is oppposite of the picture you attached, as this ST62XX is reset low instead of high voltage on the pin.

The purpose is to keep the device in reset until power rail has come all of the way up.  The RC circuit has a time constant R*C that will create the delay.

The circuit in the blue circle is a simple pull up resistor on that EEPROM's write protect line, and the blue square appears to be a voltage divider to monitor the 3.3V line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, could you maybe just explain how the capacitor would discharge once it is full and the Vcc voltage has been cut off?

Answer (score 2):

This circuit (in the black circle) causes a pulse on the pin connected to it. If the capacitor is empty it starts filling through the resistor. As the capacitor fills with charge, the current through the resistor slowly falls, and the voltage on the pin also falls. Once the capacitor is full no more current will flow an there will be "0V" on the pin.

I would also regard this as a bad design practice.

EDIT:

As the +5V supply voltage collapse to zero, the 10uF capacitor will attempt to discharge through the 10k resistor and whatever parasitic components are forming the input pin. The faster the +5V supply voltage collapses, the faster the capacitor will have to be discharged, which would cause the stress on the said parasitic components inside the integrated circuit to increase. If the stress is big enough the circuit will fail.

All of the above holds for a typical pin topology, we do not actually know how much negative voltage or current can this pin tolerate until we see the datasheet of the integrated circuit.

EDIT 1: [Datasheet](http://www.docin.com/p-52214825.html#)

Comment: so what you are saying is that this circuit provides a voltage only for a very short amount of time to the rst pin on the IC so if one wouldn't have the resistor the capacitor would fill up and its left plate would be +5V like the source connected to it and the right plate would be a negative voltage less then zero, right?

Comment: No. If there would be no resistor, there would be no reason for the capacitor to fill, assuming of course the input pin is Hi impedance. As far as the  timing is concearned, you can calculate/simulate this, its a simple RC constant. It's not that short.

Comment: Why do you consider this bad design practice?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: +1 really bad design practice. Even with a series resistor on the input to limit the current (which should be a minimum), it does not generate a reliable reset pulse under all possible conditions (for example, a slow ramp up with a blip).

Comment: How would the capacitor discharge through the resistor? Once the capacitor is full it will have Vcc across it and the side where the resistor is has potential same as ground, that is 0. So the charge on the left plate would have to go through the insulation between the plates in order to go through the resistor and into ground.

Comment: @adoion: I saw you already opened another question about this and also got the answer. I think this design is NOK as the datasheet states the most negative voltage on this pin may be -0.3V This pin is probably protected by internal diodes. Usually these are not really capable of carying lots of current.

Answer (score 2):

Is the pin that the RC circuit in the black circle connects to called "RST"?  If so, that RC circuit provides a power-on reset pulse - when power is applied, the capacitor will pull that pin up to Vcc, then will be charged through the resistor, allowing the voltage on the pin to drop.

The resistor in the blue circle appears to be a pull-up resistor to ensure that signal is held high when there is nothing driving it low.  The signal may be normally driven by an open-collector or tri-state output.

Comment: You beat me to it, exactly the same as my answer. I delete mine.

Comment: Yes the RC circuit connects to the pin RST, but if you don't mid answering how the capacitor would discharge once fully charged, it cant be through the resistor??

Comment: Yes, when the power is switched off, the capacitor will discharge through the resistor.  As iggy indicates in his answer, this depends on protection diodes in the IC to also carry the capacitor's discharge current.  A better circuit would have a diode across the resistor, anode to ground, to discharge the capacitor.

Comment: But it is not possible to be discharged through the resistor. Once the capacitor is charged it will have a +5vcc on the left plate and 0V on the right plate so the charge would have to go through the capacitor insulation through the resistor and to ground witch is impossible unless the capacitor is bad ??

Comment: The charge is between the plates of the capacitor, not on just on the left plate.  When the power is turned off, the left side of the capacitor will be taken to ground as the supply voltage falls.  The 5 volts across the capacitor will try to push the right plate to -5 volts, but the protective diodes in the IC, and the resistor, will discharge the capacitor, eventually bringing both plates to ground potential, and leaving no charge on the capacitor.